# sqlite references conflict when installing sqlite-net-extensions

Tags: c#, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm trying to add sqlite-net-extensions to my project, but seems like it's installing sqlite 3.05 instead of working with the existing 3.10
Getting this-

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Source  Suppression
>   State Error       An assembly with the same simple name 'SQLite.Net' has
>   already been imported. Try removing one of the references (e.g.
>   'C:\Users\xxx.nuget\packages\SQLite.Net-PCL\3.0.5\lib\Windows8\SQLite.Net.dll')
>   or sign them to enable side-by-side.  TymIt

If I had the sqlite refereces in the solution i could just remove the 3.05 one, but the thing is they're only listed in "Unversal Windows" reference, where I get both "SQLite.Net[3.0.5.0]" and "SQLite.Net[3.1.0.0]"

At a loss here..

Comment: It seems to work when I remove the SQLite-net-pcl package, and just install the extensions one (which automatically adds the 3.05).. but I wonder if there's another solution available where I could use the newer version

Comment: Currently SQLite.Net 3.1.0 breaks compatibility with SQLite.Net 3.0.5. You should stick to 3.0.5 until a new version of SQLite-Net Extensions is released.

Comment: yep, that's what I've done eventually- just downloaded 3.05
Thanks

Comment: I just had the same problem. I get this only running UWP project on xamarin solution but Android project works fine. I removed and reinstalled but still getting this error. it is really strange for me.

Comment: btw, there is pre-release already has latest sqlite.net included.